# How to send in Angular http post request with data + image?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

In a post request (in Angular), I usually send data (for example like 'product' data) using an 'object':

```
product: any = {}; // filled of proprieties (code, barcode, name, description...)
```

and then pass this in the request:

```
return this.http
      .post<any>( Url , product)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
```

using ExpressJS I can easly retrieve the proprieties 'req.body.<< propriety >>' :

```
router.post("/newProduct",  function (req, res, next) {

  const code = req.body.code;
  const barcode = req.body.barcode;
  const nameProduct = req.body.name;
  const description = req.body.description;

  //.. here other code - mySql to insert data in the DB ..

});
```

**THE PROBLEM**

Now I would like to send the same data (like in the example) and also an image to save on the server.

**PS**

I tried to use FormData:

```
var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', imageFile);
    formData.append('product', product);

return this.http
      .post<any>(this.newProductUrl, formData )
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
```

So in the backend, I can retrieve and save the image using the npm package 'multer' but then I don't know how to get the 'product' data.

Comment: how do you retrieve the image in multer? can you post some code?

Answer (score 1):

You can access your image data added in formData with 'request.file' and your others data will be available on 'request.body'

To Upload the image in backend multer.upload('image') will be used. Here image is the key that you have in your formdata.

// frontend

```
var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', imageFile);
    formData.append('product', product);
```

// backend

```
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' }) // uploads your destination folder

app.post('/profile', upload.single('image'), function (req, res, next) {
   // req.file is the `image` file
   // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
});
```

Comment: @RoccoDen91 I didn't say that

Comment: @RoccoDen91 I did not write that answer. Please take a look again. It says there who answered. I only edited unnecessary information out of this answer. I can't help you. Please do not ping me.

Comment: @Khushbu31 As you said I can correctly get and save the image file with req.file and using 'multer' but I'm still not able to get the 'product fields' For test it, I tried to print something: console.log("req.body"); console.log(req.body); //print this: [Object: null prototype] { product: '[object Object]' } console.log("req.body.product"); console.log(req.body.product); //print this: [object Object] console.log("req.body.product.code"); console.log(req.body.product.code); //print this: undefined So, how can I for example access to the field 'code' ?